# Replace matching values from one dataframe with index value from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to replace the fruit strings in **df1['fruit']** with the corresponding ID from **df2['id']**. Essentially I'm trying to create a lookup table for fruit.

**df1**

| fruit | store | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | heb | 0.99 |
| orange | heb | 0.69 |
| apple | kroger | 0.88 |
| apple | walmart | 0.89 |
| banana | heb | 0.59 |
| banana | walmart | 0.59 |
| orange | kroger | 0.39 |

**df2**

| id | fruit |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | apple |
| 1 | orange |
| 2 | banana |

I'd like to modify **df1** to look like this (preferably in-place):

**df1**

| fruit | store | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | heb | 0.99 |
| 1 | heb | 0.69 |
| 0 | kroger | 0.88 |
| 0 | walmart | 0.89 |
| 2 | heb | 0.59 |
| 2 | walmart | 0.59 |
| 1 | kroger | 0.39 |

This seems like a simple enough thing to do, but I'm pretty new to Pandas so I could use some help. All of the googling and stackoverflow-ing I've done hasn't quite answered the question yet. Also, eventually I'd also like to create a lookup dataframe to do the same kind of replacement of store name strings in **df1['store']**

Here are some things I've tried so far:

**.loc**
`df1.loc[df1['fruit'] == df2['fruit'], 'fruit'] = df2['id']`

This results in the following error: `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

**.where**

`df1.where(df1['fruit'] == df2['fruit'], other= df2['id'], inplace=True)`

I know I have this all wrong, since `where` should be replacing values based on a false condition. Also, it doesn't work, so there's another clue I'm on the wrong path :)

**.replace**

I don't have this code anymore, but I tried converting **df2** into a dict and replacing values in **df1** conditionally.

I know I'm close! This is something I need to do a lot...replace values in one dataframe based on values from another dataframe. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Many topics on SO about this already. `df2['fruit'].map(df1.set_index('fruit')['id'])`.

Comment: `df1.merge(df2,on='fruit')`

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang but that results in a ```KeyError: 'id'```

Comment: Thanks @AnuragDabas this is really close to what I want, and I could use it if there isn't a better method. Is it possible to do this kind of operation without having to drop df1['fruit'] and rename the newly added df1['id'] column to 'fruit'?

Comment: btw you don't need to drop df1['fruit'] and rename the newly added df1['id'] column to 'fruit?...I mean what do you mean..sorry I didn't understand **:(**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY:

```
df1['fruit'] = df1.fruit.map(dict(df2[['fruit','id']].values))
```

Comment: I've found that if one of the values in a row equals None, this solution changes the entire column data type from int to float. Do you have any idea why it does that?

Comment: because NAN in pandas can't be represented via INT. You can use df[<col_name>].as_type('INT32') or df = df.convert_dtypes()

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most pythonic way of doing this, and there is surely pandas built-in function to do this (I encourage you check the documentation) but here is a solution that works.

You can achieve that by creating a mapping function and applying it to your column.

**Mapping function:**

- Creates a dict of correspondance between fruits and their codes from `fd2`
- returns the associated value if existing or the original value if not.

here's the function:

```
def mapping(x):
    mapping_dict = df2.set_index("fruit")['id']
    try:
        return mapping_dict[x]
    except:
        return x #or whatever to indicate that the fruit is not in df2
```

**Apply it to df1:**

```
df1['fruit'] = df1['fruit'].apply(mapping)
```